# Conditional Up and Back Actions with Android Navigation Component Library

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

How to provide conditional Up and Back navigation when using Android's Navigation Component library?

For example, my app has a contact book. When creating a new contact, if the user presses back before filling out any info, I'd like to go back to the list of contacts. If the user filled out info, I'd like to go to the detail view of that contact.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment's `onCreate`, add an `OnBackPressedCallback` callback:

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
        backOrUpPressed()
    }
}
```

Then, after you setup your toolbar with the `NavController`, set a `NavigationOnClickListener`:

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Setup the view

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    toolbar.setupWithNavController(findNavController(), AppBarConfiguration(findNavController().graph))
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { backOrUpPressed() }
}
```

Then implement your custom Up/Back logic in `backorUpPressed()`